# jquery add html content to div from struts action class variable

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am trying to add HTML content into a div on page load. This HTML content is coming from a struts action class variable. I have tested that the I get the HTML content passed to the resultant jsp file but the problem is that I don't get how to add it inside a particular div from struts action class variable.

I want to append it to topcontblock div shown below:

```
<div class="main nobg">
<div class="topcontblock" id="contentBlock">
//my html content here
</div>
</div>
```

I am really stuck on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you already have HTML content why do you need javascript to add it to div?

Comment: What is the problem you stuck, how did you try to resolve?

Comment: the problem is that the HTML content contains some directives like include some other HTML page, if-else statement etc. which I want to get evaluated after the content is appended to the div. I am sorry if it seems simple. I am quite new to this framework.

Comment: Then you really need to go [here](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: Or here: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/tag-reference.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output a `Struts2` `Action` variable (with its `Getter` provided) by using the `<s:property />` tag:

```
<s:property value="yourVariableName"/>
```

By default, for security reasons, `HTML` tags contained in a variable are escaped (and hence not evaluated) while injecting it into a page. To prevent that, you can modify the attribute `escapeHtml` to false:

```
<s:property value="yourVariableName" escapeHtml="false" />
```

But you should stop for a moment and ask yourself if an `Action` variable is really the right place for the snippet you want to inject; it would probably be better to define it in another JSP, and include it with `<s:include />` directive.

Comment: hey Andrea, Thanks for the reply. I have already tried it already and got it resolved. Now the other problem is that I have some directives like including another jsp file in the value of variable set by the action class i.e. the variable containing HTML content. Yeah I know that action class variable would not be good to store the HTML content but it is needed in my case. As I need to implement a functionality where the admin can alter the contents of particular page from UI, the modified content is the  stored in DB. Later on this content is picked from DB and placed in a div.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to go on this?

Comment: If you've solved, you should mark the solution as the accepted answer, and start asking new questions. Btw, for your needs, have you ever thought about WYSIWYG editors like CKEditor or TinyMCE ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add it using:

```
   $("div#contentBlock").html("here you can put your HTML code");
```

or if you have your content as an object

```
   $("div#contentBlock").append($("<span>").addClass("your class"));
```